# Angular2 Cli installation problems

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

I want to give a shot at angular 2 so I'm working to install angular2 cli now, but when I install it and then run `ng new newapp` , it awkwardly opens the command line and says something about 'mg' (not even 'ng').

Here's what happens when I run `'ng new myapp'`

[image]

I'm running `sudo npm install -g angular-cli@latest` which gives the following output:

```
npm WARN engine angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.19-3: wanted: {"node":">= 4.1.0","npm":">= 3.0.0"} (current: {"node":"4.6.1","npm":"2.15.9"})
npm WARN engine @ngtools/webpack@1.1.4: wanted: {"node":">= 4.1.0","npm":">= 3.0.0"} (current: {"node":"4.6.1","npm":"2.15.9"})
npm WARN engine @angular-cli/ast-tools@1.0.7: wanted: {"node":">= 4.1.0","npm":">= 3.0.0"} (current: {"node":"4.6.1","npm":"2.15.9"})
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@1.0.15
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.

> execSync@1.0.2 install /home/user/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/angular2-template-loader/node_modules/codecov/node_modules/execSync
> node install.js

[execsync v1.0.2] Attempting to compile native extensions.
[execSync v1.0.2]
    Native code compile failed!!
npm WARN deprecated tough-cookie@2.2.2: ReDoS vulnerability parsing Set-Cookie https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/130
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue

> node-zopfli@2.0.1 install /home/user/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/compression-webpack-plugin/node_modules/node-zopfli
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(403): https://node-zopfli.s3.amazonaws.com/Release/zopfli-v2.0.1-node-v46-linux-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for node-zopfli@2.0.1 and node@4.6.1 (node-v46 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
make: Entering directory '/home/user/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/compression-webpack-plugin/node_modules/node-zopfli/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/src/zopfli-binding.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/src/png/zopflipng.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopfli/blocksplitter.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopfli/cache.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopfli/deflate.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopfli/gzip_container.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopfli/hash.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopfli/katajainen.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopfli/lz77.o
In file included from ../zopfli/src/zopfli/lz77.c:21:0:
../zopfli/src/zopfli/symbols.h:38:12: warning: ‘ZopfliGetDistExtraBits’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static int ZopfliGetDistExtraBits(int dist) {
            ^
../zopfli/src/zopfli/symbols.h:61:12: warning: ‘ZopfliGetDistExtraBitsValue’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static int ZopfliGetDistExtraBitsValue(int dist) {
            ^
../zopfli/src/zopfli/symbols.h:138:12: warning: ‘ZopfliGetLengthExtraBits’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static int ZopfliGetLengthExtraBits(int l) {
            ^
../zopfli/src/zopfli/symbols.h:161:12: warning: ‘ZopfliGetLengthExtraBitsValue’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static int ZopfliGetLengthExtraBitsValue(int l) {
            ^
../zopfli/src/zopfli/symbols.h:222:12: warning: ‘ZopfliGetLengthSymbolExtraBits’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static int ZopfliGetLengthSymbolExtraBits(int s) {
            ^
../zopfli/src/zopfli/symbols.h:231:12: warning: ‘ZopfliGetDistSymbolExtraBits’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static int ZopfliGetDistSymbolExtraBits(int s) {
            ^
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopfli/squeeze.o
In file included from ../zopfli/src/zopfli/squeeze.c:28:0:
../zopfli/src/zopfli/symbols.h:61:12: warning: ‘ZopfliGetDistExtraBitsValue’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static int ZopfliGetDistExtraBitsValue(int dist) {
            ^
../zopfli/src/zopfli/symbols.h:161:12: warning: ‘ZopfliGetLengthExtraBitsValue’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static int ZopfliGetLengthExtraBitsValue(int l) {
            ^
../zopfli/src/zopfli/symbols.h:222:12: warning: ‘ZopfliGetLengthSymbolExtraBits’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static int ZopfliGetLengthSymbolExtraBits(int s) {
            ^
../zopfli/src/zopfli/symbols.h:231:12: warning: ‘ZopfliGetDistSymbolExtraBits’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static int ZopfliGetDistSymbolExtraBits(int s) {
            ^
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopfli/tree.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopfli/util.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopfli/zlib_container.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopfli/zopfli_lib.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopflipng/zopflipng_lib.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopflipng/lodepng/lodepng.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopflipng/lodepng/lodepng_util.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli.node
  COPY Release/zopfli.node
  COPY /home/user/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/compression-webpack-plugin/node_modules/node-zopfli/lib/binding/node-v46-linux-x64/zopfli.node
  TOUCH Release/obj.target/action_after_build.stamp
make: Leaving directory '/home/user/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/compression-webpack-plugin/node_modules/node-zopfli/build'
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@1.0.15
npm WARN deprecated lodash-node@2.4.1: This package is discontinued. Use lodash@^4.0.0.
|
> node-sass@3.11.2 install /home/user/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Start downloading binary at https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.11.2/linux-x64-46_binding.node
Binary downloaded and installed at /home/user/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-46/binding.node

> node-sass@3.11.2 postinstall /home/user/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

"/home/user/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-46/binding.node" exists. 
 testing binary.
Binary is fine; exiting.
/home/user/.npm-packages/bin/ng -> /home/user/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/bin/ng
angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.19-3 /home/user/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/angular-cli
├── ember-cli-string-utils@1.0.0
├── json-loader@0.5.4
├── raw-loader@0.5.1
├── expose-loader@0.7.1
├── script-loader@0.7.0
├── symlink-or-copy@1.1.6
├── fs.realpath@1.0.0
├── rimraf@2.5.4
├── @angular-cli/base-href-webpack@1.0.6
├── denodeify@1.2.1
├── exit@0.1.2
├── karma-sourcemap-loader@0.3.7 (graceful-fs@4.1.10)
├── @ngtools/webpack@1.1.4
├── parse5@2.2.3
├── chalk@1.1.3 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.5, ansi-styles@2.2.1, supports-color@2.0.0, strip-ansi@3.0.1, has-ansi@2.0.0)
├── file-loader@0.8.5 (loader-utils@0.2.16)
├── url-loader@0.5.7 (mime@1.2.11, loader-utils@0.2.16)
├── opn@4.0.1 (object-assign@4.1.0, pinkie-promise@2.0.1)
├── style-loader@0.13.1 (loader-utils@0.2.16)
├── sass-loader@3.2.3 (object-assign@4.1.0, async@1.5.2, loader-utils@0.2.16)
├── silent-error@1.0.1 (debug@2.2.0)
├── zone.js@0.6.26
├── @angular/platform-server@2.1.2
├── fs-extra@0.30.0 (path-is-absolute@1.0.1, klaw@1.3.1, graceful-fs@4.1.10, jsonfile@2.4.0)
├── glob@7.1.1 (path-is-absolute@1.0.1, inherits@2.0.3, inflight@1.0.6, once@1.4.0, minimatch@3.0.3)
├── ts-loader@0.8.2 (object-assign@2.1.1, arrify@1.0.1, semver@5.3.0, colors@1.1.2, loader-utils@0.2.16, enhanced-resolve@0.9.1)
├── tslint-loader@2.1.5 (object-assign@4.1.0, strip-json-comments@1.0.4, loader-utils@0.2.16, mkdirp@0.5.1)
├── stylus-loader@2.3.1 (loader-utils@0.2.16, when@3.6.4)
├── shelljs@0.7.5 (interpret@1.0.1, rechoir@0.6.2)
├── less-loader@2.2.3 (loader-utils@0.2.16)
├── webpack-merge@0.14.1 (lodash.isequal@4.4.0, lodash.merge@3.3.2, lodash.isplainobject@3.2.0, lodash.find@3.2.1)
├── resolve@1.1.7
├── source-map-loader@0.1.5 (async@0.9.2, loader-utils@0.2.16, source-map@0.1.43)
├── exports-loader@0.6.3 (loader-utils@0.2.16, source-map@0.1.43)
├── webpack-md5-hash@0.0.5 (md5@2.2.1)
├── offline-plugin@3.4.2 (deep-extend@0.4.1, loader-utils@0.2.16, es6-promise@3.3.1, minimatch@3.0.3, ejs@2.5.2)
├── enhanced-resolve@2.3.0 (object-assign@4.1.0, graceful-fs@4.1.10, tapable@0.2.4, memory-fs@0.3.0)
├── postcss-loader@0.9.1 (loader-utils@0.2.16, postcss@5.2.5)
├── @angular/compiler-cli@2.1.2 (minimist@1.2.0, reflect-metadata@0.1.8)
├── npm-run-all@3.1.1 (object-assign@4.1.0, pinkie-promise@2.0.1, read-pkg-up@1.0.1, shell-quote@1.6.1, minimatch@3.0.3, cross-spawn@4.0.2, ps-tree@1.1.0, read-pkg@1.1.0, string.prototype.padend@3.0.0)
├── @angular/common@2.1.2
├── @angular/platform-browser@2.1.2
├── leek@0.0.21 (debug@2.2.0, lodash.assign@3.2.0, rsvp@3.3.3, request@2.78.0)
├── sourcemap-istanbul-instrumenter-loader@0.2.0 (object-assign@4.1.0, loader-utils@0.2.16, istanbul@0.4.5)
├── istanbul-instrumenter-loader@0.2.0 (object-assign@4.1.0, loader-utils@0.2.16, istanbul@0.4.5)
├── webpack-dev-server@2.1.0-beta.9 (connect-history-api-fallback@1.3.0, strip-ansi@3.0.1, supports-color@3.1.2, opn@4.0.2, compression@1.6.2, express@4.14.0, webpack-dev-middleware@1.8.4, spdy@3.4.4, http-proxy-middleware@0.17.2, chokidar@1.6.1, sockjs@0.3.18, serve-index@1.8.0, sockjs-client@1.1.1, yargs@4.8.1)
├── angular2-template-loader@0.5.0 (loader-utils@0.2.16, codecov@1.0.1)
├── stylus@0.54.5 (css-parse@1.7.0, debug@2.2.0, mkdirp@0.5.1, glob@7.0.6, source-map@0.1.43, sax@0.5.8)
├── html-webpack-plugin@2.24.1 (toposort@1.0.0, loader-utils@0.2.16, bluebird@3.4.6, html-minifier@3.1.0, pretty-error@2.0.2)
├── handlebars@4.0.5 (async@1.5.2, source-map@0.4.4, optimist@0.6.1, uglify-js@2.7.4)
├── typescript@2.0.7
├── common-tags@1.3.1 (babel-runtime@6.18.0)
├── awesome-typescript-loader@2.2.4 (object-assign@4.1.0, colors@1.1.2, loader-utils@0.2.16, source-map-support@0.4.6)
├── remap-istanbul@0.6.4 (amdefine@1.0.0, source-map@0.5.6, through2@2.0.1, gulp-util@3.0.7, istanbul@0.4.3)
├── @angular/tsc-wrapped@0.3.0 (tsickle@0.1.7)
├── compression-webpack-plugin@0.3.2 (async@0.2.10, webpack-sources@0.1.2, node-zopfli@2.0.1)
├── tslint@3.15.1 (colors@1.1.2, diff@2.2.3, optimist@0.6.1, findup-sync@0.3.0, underscore.string@3.3.4)
├── @angular/core@2.1.2
├── @angular/compiler@2.1.2
├── string-replace-loader@1.0.5 (loader-utils@0.2.16, lodash@3.10.1)
├── webpack@2.1.0-beta.25 (object-assign@4.1.0, interpret@1.0.1, tapable@0.2.4, async@1.5.2, clone@1.0.2, supports-color@3.1.2, loader-utils@0.2.16, loader-runner@2.2.0, source-map@0.5.6, mkdirp@0.5.1, acorn@3.3.0, memory-fs@0.3.0, webpack-sources@0.1.2, uglify-js@2.7.4, watchpack@1.1.0, ajv@4.8.2, yargs@4.8.1, node-libs-browser@1.0.0)
├── karma-webpack@1.8.0 (async@0.9.2, loader-utils@0.2.16, source-map@0.1.43, webpack-dev-middleware@1.8.4, lodash@3.10.1)
├── protractor@3.3.0 (jasminewd2@0.0.9, q@1.4.1, adm-zip@0.4.7, source-map-support@0.4.6, glob@6.0.4, optimist@0.6.1, saucelabs@1.0.1, jasmine@2.4.1, request@2.67.0, selenium-webdriver@2.52.0)
├── typedoc@0.4.5 (progress@1.1.8, marked@0.3.6, minimatch@3.0.3, typedoc-default-themes@0.4.0, typescript@1.8.10, highlight.js@9.8.0)
├── css-loader@0.23.1 (postcss-modules-extract-imports@1.0.1, object-assign@4.1.0, loader-utils@0.2.16, postcss-modules-values@1.2.2, css-selector-tokenizer@0.5.4, source-list-map@0.1.6, lodash.camelcase@3.0.1, postcss-modules-scope@1.0.2, postcss-modules-local-by-default@1.1.1, postcss@5.2.5, cssnano@3.8.0)
├── less@2.7.1 (graceful-fs@4.1.10, mime@1.3.4, image-size@0.5.0, source-map@0.5.6, errno@0.1.4, mkdirp@0.5.1, promise@7.1.1)
├── lodash@4.16.6
├── core-js@2.4.1
├── rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12 (symbol-observable@1.0.4)
├── @angular-cli/ast-tools@1.0.7 (rxjs@5.0.0-beta.11)
├── node-sass@3.11.2 (get-stdin@4.0.1, lodash.assign@4.2.0, lodash.clonedeep@4.5.0, async-foreach@0.1.3, in-publish@2.0.0, nan@2.4.0, mkdirp@0.5.1, cross-spawn@3.0.1, gaze@1.1.2, npmlog@4.0.0, meow@3.7.0, request@2.78.0, sass-graph@2.1.2, node-gyp@3.4.0)
└── ember-cli@2.5.0 (ember-cli-test-info@1.0.0, ember-cli-path-utils@1.0.0, ember-cli-is-package-missing@1.0.0, clean-base-url@1.0.0, ember-cli-normalize-entity-name@1.0.0, get-caller-file@1.0.2, fs-monitor-stack@1.1.1, git-repo-info@1.3.1, broccoli-funnel-reducer@1.0.0, ember-cli-valid-component-name@1.0.0, ember-cli-get-component-path-option@1.0.0, is-git-url@0.2.3, escape-string-regexp@1.0.5, promise-map-series@0.2.3, isbinaryfile@2.0.4, broccoli-plugin@1.2.2, broccoli-source@1.1.0, exists-sync@0.0.3, semver@5.3.0, filesize@3.3.0, inflection@1.10.0, bower-endpoint-parser@0.2.2, broccoli-viz@2.0.1, node-modules-path@1.0.1, through@2.3.8, amd-name-resolver@0.0.5, broccoli-sane-watcher@1.1.5, walk-sync@0.2.7, node-uuid@1.4.7, portfinder@1.0.9, nopt@3.0.6, debug@2.2.0, http-proxy@1.15.2, minimatch@3.0.3, readline2@0.1.1, diff@2.2.3, temp@0.8.3, findup@0.1.5, morgan@1.7.0, glob@7.0.3, configstore@2.1.0, fs-tree-diff@0.4.4, broccoli-funnel@1.0.9, rsvp@3.3.3, merge-defaults@0.2.1, ora@0.2.3, mkdirp@0.5.1, broccoli-kitchen-sink-helpers@0.3.1, quick-temp@0.1.5, fs-extra@0.26.7, compression@1.6.2, sane@1.4.1, findup-sync@0.2.1, express@4.14.0, broccoli-config-replace@1.1.2, inquirer@0.12.0, cpr@0.4.2, tree-sync@1.1.4, broccoli-merge-trees@1.1.4, yam@0.0.18, ember-router-generator@1.2.2, ember-cli-broccoli@0.16.9, broccoli-config-loader@1.0.0, tiny-lr@0.2.1, broccoli-concat@2.3.8, markdown-it@4.3.0, markdown-it-terminal@0.0.3, testem@1.13.0, ember-cli-preprocess-registry@2.0.0, core-object@0.0.2, bower-config@1.4.0, broccoli-babel-transpiler@5.6.1, bower@1.7.9, npm@2.14.21)
```

Trying to debug it, I tried the minimatch installaton by running  `sudo npm install -g minimatch@3.0.2`, which gives me this output.

```
minimatch@3.0.2 /home/user/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/minimatch
└── brace-expansion@1.1.6 (balanced-match@0.4.2, concat-map@0.0.1)
```

But when I do  `npm minimatch -v`   it gives me this `2.15.9`

Any suggestions?

Comment: what's the error message when you run `ng new` command?

Comment: @SefaÜmitOray there's no error per say, it's just a command line thing that pops up. I just updated the post with a screenshot. It's the most bizarre thing...

Comment: Do you got the latest nodejs installed? It could be the problem..

Comment: Just updated to node 6 and tried to reinstall. Same error.

Comment: Personally, I'd discourage installing this tool as `@latest` - it's a _beta_ for a reason. Try cleaning up your current installation and then downgrade to an officially released version (`@v1.0.0-beta.19`).

Comment: Your npm is outdated. Try `npm install -g npm@latest` and retry to check for errors as this could be related. Also, newest stable version of angular-cli is called `@angular/cli`. So `npm uninstall -g angular-cli` followed by `npm install -g @angular/cli`. Also try `npm cache clean` from time to time when errors maintain.

Answer (score 0):

It should be npm install **@angular/cli** -g not **angular/cli**. I also recommended not using '@latest'. Uninstall all with: npm uninstall angular/cli then run npm install -g @angular/cli. Should work for you.